# Total Variation of a bounded variation function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) = cos(x)$, I want to calculate the total variation of $f$ on the interval $[0,3\pi]$, but i don't know how to aproach to this. 
I've found that $3\pi$ is upper bound to the variation but i don't know how to prove that there's not a better bound.

Comment: On which interval?

Comment: It 's on $[0,3\pi]$

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{3\pi}|\sin(x)|\,dx = 6$$

Comment: It would help to know what material you are studying, for which this exercise is intended to be a lesson reinforcement.  There's always the definition of *total variation* to consider as a starting point, but Readers can only guess whether the definition is known to you.

Answer (score 0):

As your $f$ is differentiable, its total variation on $[a,b]$ is given by

$$V_a^b(f) = \int_a^b |f'(x)|\,dx = \int_0^{3\pi}|\sin(x)|\,dx\,.$$

Can you take it from here?